# Prestashop 1.6 session/cookie with smarty

Tags: php, session, cookies, smarty, prestashop

In my prestashop a user (that is not a client or an admin) can create a "side" account (that is not a prestashop account) to do something special on the site.

I have created the everything to do that but when the user connect i can not keep the data during the session.

I've look for a way to keep the data and the only thing i see is the smarty cookie. Fine by me BUT i can not control the lifetime of that cookie. And i need this cookie to die when the user close the browser.

So i've tried to do a session, but i can't get it to work and i didn't see a way to do a cookie that doesn't last.

Anyone has an idea to do a session like data, or to handle the cookie lifespan?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `CookieCore` class

```
//to write
$cookie = new Cookie('my_cookie'); //make your own cookie
$cookie->setExpire(time() + 20 * 60); // 20 minutes for example
$cookie->variable_name = 'hello';
$cookie->write();

//to read
$cookie = new Cookie('my_cookie');
echo $cookie->variable_name;
//hello
```

Answer (score 3):

I gonna add to the message of UnLoCo.

For people looking for a cookie that die at the end of the session, just put the

```
$cookie->setExpire(0);
```

NB the cookie will die only when the browser is completly close (i have an extention feedly that let the browser open, so i though there was a bug)

And last thing if you want to kill the cookie yourself

```
$cookie = new Cookie('my_cookie');
$cookie->variable_name = null;
$cookie->write();
```

Comment: To delete all cookie data, you can use `$cookie->logout();` before `write()`

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Prestashop 1.6.1.x

Original Post with few corrections 
http://vblanch.com/get-the-contact-email-in-prestashop-shop-name-and-set-values-in-cookies/

If you also need to put values into cookies:

```
$this->context->cookie->__set('name_of_your_key', $your_value);
```

To get the value from a smarty template (.tpl):

```
{$cookie->name_of_your_key}
```

From PHP (inside a controller):

```
$this->context->cookie->name_of_your_key
```

Outside of a controller:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->cookie->name_of_your_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SESSION in Prestashop only with this parameters `$_SESSION['VIEW']`
Other sessions has be destroy